# Use Perl idioms $/ and q|| to read text file blockwise

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand some **Perl** code that is used to read a text file block-wise.

The text file `MYFILE`looks like this:

```
First block
First Line: Something in here
Second Line: More here
Third Line: etc.

Second block
First Line: Something in here
Second Line: More here
Third Line: etc.
```

The code is used to extract the lines of a block where a regular expression is found *(and it works fine, I just want to understand it)*.

This is the part of the code that I don't understand:

```
local $/ = q||;
while (<MYFILE>) {
    do something;
}
```

Could someone explain to me what the line `local $/ = q||;` is doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$/` is the [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). "This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is". Setting it to empty string, i.e., `''` causes the blank line to split the records. `q||` notation quotes the stuff within pipes so `q||` is the same as `''`. You can use a variety of delimiters with the `q` prefix: `q(), q//` are also the same.

Comment: Pedantically, `q||` is the same as `''`.  `qq||` would be the same as `""`.

Comment: I like to consider `''` as a shorthand of `q''`

Answer (score 3):

```
local $/ = q||;
```

This will treat empty line as "record separator".

```
local $/ = q||;
    while(<$fh>) {
        # each loop, $_ will be a different record
        # the first will be "First block\nFirst Line: Something in here\nSecond Line: More here\nThird Line: etc.\n\n"
        # etc.
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

`local $/ = q||;` is same as `local $/ = '';`

Check [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

`local` will temporarily using [dynamic scope](http://perl.plover.com/local.html#5_Dynamic_Scope) set global variable `$/` ([input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) to empty string, so input records are terminated by one **or more** empty lines.